# How would meteor work with jQuery plugins for table rendering?

Tags: meteor

Like datatables or jQgrid? Or is only template based rendering supported for updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you can't just include them into the head section without using some code to defer their loading until Jquery has loaded.
I have however proposed a change:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/47

This should allow you to just place the script file into your head section. I'm also going to look into allowing you to place it at the end of the body too.

Comment: If you create a package that [declares the dependency on jQuery](https://github.com/dandv/meteor-jquery-rateit/blob/master/package.js#L6), you'll be fine. Meteor will load jQuery before your package.

Answer (score 2):

I´m using slick.grid without a problem with Meteor...

You basically have to:

- Initially populate the grid with data
- Use the Observe Method of Meteor to push new data into the Grid. Nice place for triggering insert/remove Animations.

Comment: can you add some examples plz ?

Comment: examples would be very helpful

Comment: Looks like the answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14925420/meteor-with-datatables-meteor-atflush-typeerror) provides an example of this