# how to properly handle dom ready for Meteor

Tags: meteor

I am currently using iron-router and this is my very first attempt to try out the Meteor platform. I has been running into issues where most of the jquery libraries failed to initialized properly because the of the way Meteor renders html, $(document).ready() fires before any templates are rendered. I am wondering is there any callbacks from Meteor/iron-router that allows me to replace the jQuery's dom ready?

Also, how should I (easily and properly)  handle the live update of the dom elements if some of them are customized by jQuery/javascript?

This is what i am currently doing, i feel like it is very hackish and probably would run into issues if the elements got updated after the initialization.

```
var jsInitalized = false;

Router.map(function () {
  this.route('', {
    path: '/',
    layoutTemplate: 'default',
    after: function(){
      if(!jsInitalized){
        setTimeout(function(){
          $(document).ready( function() { $$$(); });
        }, 0);
        jsInitalized = true;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

With Meteor you generally want to think about when a *template* is ready, not when the *dom* is ready.

For example, let's say you want to use the jQuery DataTables plugin to add sorting to a table element that's created by a template.  You would listen to the template's rendered event and bind the plugin to the dom:

HTML:

```
<template name="data_table">
  <table class="table table-striped" id="tblData">
  </table>
</template>
```

JavaScript:

```
Template.data_table.rendered = function () {
  $('#tblData').dataTable();
};
```

Now anytime the template is re-rendered (for example, if the data changes), your handler will be called and you can bind the jQuery plugin to the dom again.

This is the general approach.  For a complete example (that includes populating the table with rows) see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15165908/194957).

Comment: Does this work if the template you're referring to is used multiple times, e.g. in a list, and you want to perform an action once all 3 have been rendered ?

Answer (score 9):

Try making a separate .js file, call it rendered.js if you'd like. and then;

```
Template.layout.rendered = function ()
{
    $(document).ready(function(){console.log('ready')});
}
```

I use template layout, but you can do Template.default.rendered. I hope that helps.

Also take a look at this part of documentation, especially the Template.events; http://docs.meteor.com/#templates_api

Comment: Maybe this is old cause I get a javascript exception with this: TypeError: undefined is not an object

Comment: Yea, you'll probably need to use "Template.layout.onRendered" now.

Answer (score 3):

I use Meteor v0.8.0 with Iron Router (under Windows 7) and here is how I handle 'DOM ready':

***When I want to modify the DOM after a specific template has been rendered:***

I use `Template.myTemplateName.rendered` on the client side :

```
Template.blog.rendered = function()
{
    $('#addPost').click(function() 
    { 
        ...
    });
}
```

***When I want to modify the DOM after any new path has been rendered:***

I use `Router.onAfterAction`, but there seems to be a trick:

```
Router.onAfterAction(function()
{
    setTimeout(function() 
    {
        $('.clickable').click(function() 
        { 
            ...
        });
    }, 0);
});
```

Notice the `setTimeout(..., 0)`, it doesn't work for me otherwise (DOM empty).

Notice that you can use `onAfterAction` on specific path, but most of the time I think it is redundant with the `Template.myTemplateName.rendered` method above.

***What seems to be missing:***

A way to modify the DOM after *any* template has been rendered.

Comment: This is one among dozens of Iron Router strangeness. You might want to consider using Flow Router, a much simpler router for Meteor.