# Is there a meteor function that I can call when entire app is done rendering

Tags: javascript, meteor

Is there  a meteor function that I can call when the entire app is done rendering, i.e ready? `.rendered` is only applicable for one template. But what about for all the templates. Something like Meteor.appReady()? Thanks.

EDIT:
I need to run:

```
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top -90
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    })
```

Which in essence is a jquery slide for a one page app on link events. It seems when I render it before all the templates that are using `<a>` (a link), the transitions fails, but if I render it after all have tempaltes have loaded, say with a wait in the first template's rendered function, the jquery slides work. However the wait doesn't feel like a good implementation.

Comment: Please specify the use case for that.

Comment: @saimeunt please see edits.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the templating system events for this use case, as events will get properly bound/unbound upon template creation/destruction.

I would declare the anchor click event on your top level template :

```
Template.pageLayout.events({
  "click a[href*=#]:not([href=#])":function(event,template){
    // you need to adapt your event handling code here because
    // the this context won't be the same as in a jQuery event handler
  }
});
```

This is untested code, by placing a simple `console.log` in the handler, you should see if click events are actually bound properly.

You should also account for the fact that `iron:router` catches events on anchors too, you might have to use event.preventDefault/stopPropagation if you're getting trouble with that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Not conventionally but [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20427365/518703) suggests a template subsequently triggering a `jquery` document ready function.

```
Template.layout.rendered = function ()
{
    $(document).ready(function(){console.log('ready')});
}
```

Comment: I think this code is doing the same as client-side `Meteor.startup`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to put the code inside the Tracker.afterFlush (or Deps.afterFlush) callback, which ensures that all computations are ready (including DOM). Alternatively, you could try calling Tracker.flush() (or Deps.flush()) inside the click event to force the DOM to load before you scroll to the element. See the docs [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#tracker) about Tracker.