# Meteor - DOM queries not working if markup is nested in {{#with}} block

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

**HTML**

```
<template name="formExample">
  <form>
  {{#with formData}}

    <input type="text" class="example">

  {{/with}}
  </form>
</template>
```

**JS**

```
Template.formExample.helpers({
  'formData': function() {
    return Settings.findOne({ collection_id : getCollectionId() })
  }
})


Template.formExample.rendered = function(){

  // Does not work
  console.log( $('.example'), document.querySelectorAll('.example') )
  // >> undefined []

  // Works (but obviously bad)
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log( $('.example') )
  }, 1000)

  // Does not work
  console.log( this.$('.example'), this.find('.example') )

  // >> [prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[0], context: li] null
}
```

How do I effectly query the DOM, init functions, etc, with code inside logic blocks? I expected the `template.$` and `template.find` methods to work.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you set `formData`?
I tried your example, and it seems to work.

Test: http://meteorpad.com/pad/tXKpZ6gxpGur5pDds

Comment: Sorry, edited to clarify. Getting `formData` from a collection via a helper. It works for me too, *sometimes*. I suspect because of async.

Comment: Maybe you could try wrapping it in something like $(function(){ }); or so. This might be a similar problem as yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20426951/how-to-properly-handle-dom-ready-for-meteor - could you try setting your setTimeout to 0 ms and check if you still get this weird behavior?

Comment: Still got it with a setTimeout and a self-invoking anonymous function. So strange, but there has to be a solution given how common this must be

Answer (score 0):

I find that sometimes it works too, so maybe this is a better solution.

**HTML**

```
<template name="formExample">
  <form>
    {{#with formData}}
      {{> formExampleItems}}    
    {{/with}}
  </form>
</template>

<template name="forExampleItems">
  <input type="text" class="example">
</template>
```

**JS**

```
Template.forExampleItems.onRendered(function(){
  console.log(this.$('.example'));
  ...
})
```