# Render the meteor template manually when database changes occur

Tags: jquery, meteor, datatables, meteorite

I have a meteorjs template which I am using to render some records. what I want to do is, when any change occurs in database , i want to call the template render method manually. Can I reload only a single template from the DOM to reflect the changes? my code is

```
<template name="textlines">
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover listing"
               id="content_listing-table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Text Lines</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {{#each textline}}
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" data-id={{_id}} class="edit"> {{texts}}</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {{/each}}     
           </tbody>
        </table>
</template>
```

my meteor rendered method is like

```
Template.textlines.rendered = function () {
$("#content_listing-table").dataTable();
}
```

now i want to call this `Template.textlines.rendered` method manually after CRUD oprations on database. i don't know what i am asking is right or wrong, is it possible or not. I am having some problems with dataTables. so i want to refresh the template manually each time to add the contents return by the database to the dataTable. thanks

Comment: How is `textlines` defined?

Comment: textlines is template name. and textline are coming from database

Comment: Oh, I mean `textline`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using the jQuery DataTables plugin, and you're having trouble keeping the DOM maintained by the plugin updated with your database.

If so, you can observe your collection and use their API to make changes.

For example:

```
Template.textlines.created = function() {
    var _watch = Collection.find({});
    var handle = _watch.observe({
        addedAt: function (doc, atIndex, beforeId) {
            $('#content_listing-table').dataTable().fnAddData(doc);
        },
        changedAt: function(newDoc, oldDoc, atIndex) {
            $('#content_listing-table').dataTable().fnUpdate(newDoc, atIndex);
        },
        removedAt: function(oldDoc, atIndex) {
            $('#content_listing-table').dataTable().fnDeleteRow(atIndex);
        }
    });
};
```

There's a lot more information in this StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14925420/meteor-with-datatables-meteor-atflush-typeerror/15165908#15165908).

Comment: Thanx Jrullman. I gone through both the questions. It solved the problem litlle bit.

Comment: Glad to hear it! If you think this answer is helpful to other people who may be experiencing your problem please accept it by clicking the checkmark :)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. I suspect that the upcoming Meteor UI release will make jQuery UI plugins work properly in Meteor and thus not tempt one to apply Meteor anti-patterns, but here is a stab at something that may accomplish what you want:

```
Deps.autorun(function () {
  var htmlString = Template.textlines({textlines: Textlines.find()});
  $("#content_listing-table").replaceWith(htmlString);
  $("#content_listing-table").dataTable();
});
```

With this, you'll want to replace `{{> textlines}}` with `<table id="content_listing-table">`.

Comment: thank you Donny Winston, In Deps. autorun it is unable to access the database , means ` Template.textlines({textlines: Textlines.find()});` is showing undefind.