# jQuery datatable not showing data correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, datatable, spacebars

I am building an application using Meteor. I am using the jquery datatables plugin to render a table of data.

https://www.datatables.net/

When my table loads, ALL of the data is loaded, instead of the default 'show 10 entries'. Furthermore, when I click on a column to sort, all of the data disappears and becomes "No data available in table".

Here is my html:

```
<template name="Tires">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.6/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.6/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
    //$(document).ready( function () {
        //$('#tires').DataTable();
    //});
</script>
            <h1>tires</h1>
            <br>
            <table id="tires">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Brand</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {{#each products}}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{brand}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    {{/each}}
                </tbody>
            </table>
</template>
```

Here is my template helpers page:

```
Template.Tires.onRendered(function() {
    $('#tires').DataTable();
    alert('rendred!');
});
```

Note - for development purposes, I am only showing the "Brand" column for now... Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?

Comment: Is the table you're seeing formatted as a Datatable, or is it just an HTML table?

Comment: the default of `$('#tires').DataTable();` is 10? if yes seems like the `DataTable` jQuery plugin is not loading or is loading and the html is not ready yet, try this. `Template.tires.onRendered(function(){$('#tires').DataTable();})`

Comment: @bpeterson76 - the table i'm seeing is formatted as a Datatable

Comment: @Ethaan - I tried that, still getting the same error. And yes, the default is 10.

Comment: also, if I type anything in the searchbar, the data will disappear as well

Comment: maybe the table is rendering too quickly without giving the datatable enough time to fully render/process? @bpeterson76

Comment: Can you reproduce the error in a fiddle or something?

Comment: @user1547174 i think a Meteorpad of this will be great, a minimal example

Comment: @CerlinBoss - I don't think so since I'm using spacebars (similar to handlebars) for my web templates..

Comment: i'll try to put it up on meteorpad @Ethaan

Comment: Rather than building the Datatable with the DOM method, why not try using the data you have available to you and sending it directly to Datatables?  It saves a step and cuts major overhead.  What they don't tell you about the DOM method is that it's only good to between 200-500 records, then it will bog down big time.

Comment: @bpeterson76 I see - I've been looking at the datatables documentation to connect the data directly with datatables. However, the part I don't understand is how to make an ajax call to MongoDB to do so - I created a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29761749/how-to-make-ajax-request-to-mongodb and would really appreciate if you could help...

Comment: OK, have deleted my answer. Weird. Found a solution on a somehow similar question -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/15165908/1407478 integrating dataTables in Meteor. There are used `dataTable()` in the answer, just use `DataTable()` instead.  Hope this helps you out!

Comment: Careful, the solution you found uses the old API.  It'll work, but going forward it's going to get phased out, plus the new API functions won't make sense if you look at the reference.  To change over to the new API, use the upper case call, and check this reference for conversions of the different settings: http://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert