# How to make ajax request to mongodb

Tags: javascript, ajax, mongodb, meteor, datatable

I am building an app using Meteor. I am using the jquery datatables package - www.datatables.net to present my data/records. According to the documentation, I would connect the table to my MongoDB database by:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
serverSide: true,
ajax: '/data-source'
});
```

The part I am unclear of is the 3rd line - Can someone help me understand how to make an ajax call to return data from my MongoDB database?? Here is more documentation on server-side processing for datatables:

https://datatables.net/manual/server-side

I have a collection named Products with the fields description, brand, price.

Comment: you are not doing this the meteor way. Also, you can probably make your life a lot easier by using the datatables package: https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/datatables. Basically you'll want to get the data through meteor's means of data synchronization (i.e., from a collection), and not lay your own pipe next to meteor's

Comment: Hi - I have tried that, but I am having a lot of problems with publishing custom fields based on user permissions and manipulating data so I am looking into using the stock version of datatables...

Comment: Aldeed:tabular is the package to look at for this, but it's still a work in development

Comment: I am also facing the same issues with Meteor Datatables, I have even tried aldeed:tabular but it has many issues, like if we use joins we cannot search or sort the child collections ect, Non Reactive Datatable Packages are causing many reactivity related issues

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="example">
    <thead id="dataTable-header">
        <tr>
           <th>ID</th>
           <th>NAME</th>
        </tr> 
   </thead>
</table>

var dataTable = $('#example').DataTable({
                "orderable": false,
                'searching': true,
                "paging": true,
                language: {
                    processing: "<i class='fa fa-refresh fa-spin'></i>"
                 },
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": urlData,
                "columns":[
                    {
                        "orderable": false,
                        "class": "details-control",
                        "data": null,
                        "defaultContent": ""
                    },
                    {"orderable": false, "data": "name" }
                ],
                "columnDefs": [{    
                    "targets": 3,
                    "render": function (data, type, row) {
                        return '<a name="editAnchor" class="fa fa-ban"></a>';
                    },
                    "className": 'text-center'
                }]
            });
```

urlData is your json data with fields Id and Name.